# Remove error (not resolve) Class "XY" is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa

**I want to define classes in persistence unit manually** and I am trying to remove this error I get on classes that are not listed in persistence.xml file. I am using Eclispe IDE.

I tried to use this tag in persistence unit in persistence.xml file:

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

In project-facet configuration i defined in JPA that i want to include classes manually and not auto-discover them.

Also tried restarting Eclipse, Updating Maven, Reopening project, even include these classes and the error did not go away.

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually helped is removing project-facet JPA, then cleaning project in eclipse IDE option via Project->Clean... and then adding JPA facet again.